# client-side hierarchy sorting: children-parent list from database with unknown number of levels

Tags: sorting, recursion, parent, client-side, hierarchy

We have unknown levels of children and parents in database in a table naming "list" . Every record has **Id** , **title** and **parent** (id of parent). The parent of top-level items is 0.

We want to print all rows sorted how children are under their parent. There are many solution to generate recursive list using server side scripts. But We want to sort list visually (client-side) to transfer load of server toward clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side sorting of children and parents is good idea because transfers the load of server toward clients. Also this client-side script is non-recursive and solves the problem in just one loop!

**STEP 1:**

Print all elements as html div without level architecture. However we say this menu is parent of what and child of what (set as class of div). also we keep in memory an array of id(s) naming **parentlist** to use later in client-side script.

assuming ***rs*** as recordset and ***objcon*** as connection object (In vbScript):

```
<%
parentlist="[0,"
sql="select * from list"
rs.open sql,objcon
while not rs.eof 
  parentlist=parentlist&"rs("id")&","
  %>
   <div class="child<%=rs("parent")%> parent<%=rs("id")%>"><%=rs("title")%></div>
  <%
  rs.movenext
wend
rs.close
'removing last comma and closing array
parentlist=Left(parentlist,Len(parentlist)-1)&"]" 
%>
```

it would be good idea to set padding for div(s) if you want to group children visually rather than listing them below their parents.

**STEP 2:**

by looping though array of ***parentlist***, detach children of every parent and append them to their parent (using Jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var parentlist=<%=parentlist%>;
  for (i = 0; i < parentlist.length; i++) 
   { 
    $(".child"+parentlist[i]).detach().appendTo(".parent"+parentlist[i]);
   }
</script>
```